# Usage of Σ and Σ+ in Normal Forms

Tags: database-normalization

X → {A} ∈ Σ+
:
X → {A} is trivial or
A is a prime attribute or
X is not a proper subset of a candidate key.
According to the above theory consider the following example.

```
R = {STUDENT#, FACULTY, COURSE#, SNAME}.
Σ = {{STUDENT#} → {SNAME, DEPARTMENT},
{DEPARTMENT} → {FACULTY}}
```

In the above example Σ is considered but not Σ+ and its in 2nd normal form.If Σ don't violate normal form theories how can I imply that Σ+ also don't violate normal form theories?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your definiton of 2NF clearly:

> relation schema R with FD cover set Σ is in 2NF
>   when ... R ... for all X → {A} in Σ+ ...

Then you can unambiguously name your example values:

> R1 = {STUDENT#, FACULTY, COURSE#, SNAME}
>   Σ1 = {{STUDENT#} → {SNAME, DEPARTMENT}, {DEPARTMENT} → {FACULTY}}

Then you can write your hypothesis clearly:

> if relation schema R1 with FD cover set Σ1 is in 2NF
>   then relation schema R1 with FD cover set Σ1+ is in 2NF

Then you can substitute the arguments for the parameters in the definition:

> if ... R1... for all X → {A} in Σ1+ ...
>   then ... R1... for all X → {A} in Σ1++ ...

Then you can show that for all FD sets S, S++ = S+.

Then you can replace Σ1++ by Σ1+ in the latest version of the hypothesis.

(Did it matter what the values of R1 & Σ1 were?)